# Dynamics Crm solution export: missing attributes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I am on Dynamics CRM 2015 on premise. I export the default solution, and the very strange problem is that some attributes are missing in the exported solution Xml. For example: aging30, businesstypecode in the Account entity.

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago they made a change to the export process that only exports out-of-the-box attributes if they've been customized.  It's a good change, since exporting attributes that every single CRM environment has is pointless unless it's been changed.  I only know this because we noticed the same thing a while ago and came to this conclusion, I can't find any official announcement about it unfortunately.

Comment: Hello, what I need to do is compare the dev and prod solutions, I am trying the "customizations comparer" tool. I don't see any differences between the definition of the field aging30 between the 2 environments. Nevertheless, when I export the solution in dev I see the field in the Xml, while I don't see it in prod. The explanation that you report is logical, but I don't think that it is my case, since I think that the OOB attribute was not changed.

Comment: Are the front and and back-end versions identical between the two environments?  (Gear icon -> about)

Comment: Yes, the two versions are the same: 7.0.2.53 (DB 7.0.2.53).

Comment: Meaning, do the versions match across both orgs?

Comment: Yes they do match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to compare solutions from Dev and Test environments using the Customization Comparer tool. For example the OOB attribute "telephone1"  for contact entity is only showing up in Test column in Customization comparer  and not in Dev column so it is showing as missing in DEV but actually that is not the case. So what i did was open the entity attribute in CRM  for both environments and find out that on Test , Auditing for the attribute was enabled but not in Dev. So I enabled Auditing in DEV , export the solution and compare again. IT shows up in both columns and as green. Then i disabled it in DEV and reexport the solution in DEV, it shows up as  Yellow now and both columns contain the attribute with the isAuditEnabled as different value.

so my conclusion,  as Polshgiant  mentioned above, only customized OOB attributes appear in the XML when we export a  crm solution.So Sean, Just check one of the attributes that are missing in your case and make sure nothing is touched in prod.